# Displaying both a right view and a clear button in UITextField

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

After adding a right view to a `UITextField`, I am finding that it refuses to display both the right view and the clear button (having both `rightViewMode` and `clearButtonMode` set to `UITextFieldViewModeAlways`). I see the right view but the clear button is no longer displayed. I made sure that they don't overlap by having overriden `clearButtonRectForBounds` and `clearButtonRectForBounds`, to no avail.  And if I use the leftView instead of rightView, then no such issue occurs and both the left view and the clear button are displayed.

So although it does not appear to be stated in the documentation, it looks to me like the clear button is only displayed when the right view isn't displayed (and when the text property isn't a blank string). Is this correct and does anyone have a reliable workaround?  In the meantime I believe I am stuck with having to create a UIView that overlays my right view on top of a UITextField in order to get what I though I'd be getting from UITextField alone.

Answer (score 16):

you can't display both at the same time , but you can do it like this

```
UITextField * textfield = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 300, 40)];

[textfield setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];

UIImageView * imgvw = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search.jpeg"]];

[imgvw setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];

[textfield setRightView:imgvw];

[textfield setRightViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing];

[textfield setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];

[self.view addSubview:textfield];
```

Comment: Wonderful Answer!

Answer (score 4):

Yes you are right. UITextfield has properties like left and right view. If you use clear button it overlaps rightview.

Form Apple doc http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html

> If your overlay view does not overlap any other sibling views, it receives touch events like any other view. If you specify a control for your view, that control tracks and sends actions as usual. If an overlay view overlaps the clear button, however, the clear button always takes precedence in receiving events. By default, the right overlay view does overlap the clear button.

But like the name says it is a view. So you can create your own view which has 2 buttons on it and set rightview of the textfield. If you wish, you can use delegate methods of the textfield to make your buttons appear and dissapear from the view.

Comment: The documentation seems misleading.  It doesn't say that the clear button and right view are mutually exclusive.  It only says they overlap.  That makes it seem like if I used a transparent view, I would see the clear button.  However that is not the case.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue but was easily solved by 'fooling' the UITextField into using the LeftView instead of RightView. This way you can use both clear button and your supposed `rightView`. All you need to do is subclass UITextField and return the 'right corner' in `leftViewRectForBounds` and similarly update `editingRectForBounds` and `textRectForBounds`. Works perfectly.

Comment: I found it easier to just add a subview and override `editingRectForBounds/textRectForBounds` to avoid it. Didn't need to use `leftView` (since I always want my subview to show.)

Comment: If you want to add some example code, I'll give you an upvote :)

Comment: Works well but I had to override `placeholderRectForBounds` too, to make it work properly.

Answer (score 2):

I'll back up @strange 's answer (using left view instead of right) with some code:

```
-(CGRect)leftViewRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    return CGRectOffset([super leftViewRectForBounds:bounds], bounds.size.width - 30, 0);
}

-(CGRect)clearButtonRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    return CGRectOffset([super clearButtonRectForBounds:bounds], -30, 0);
}


-(CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    CGRect rect = bounds;
    rect.origin.x = 10;
    rect.size.width -= 60;
    return rect;
}


-(CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    CGRect rect = bounds;
    rect.origin.x = 10;
    rect.size.width -= 60;
    return rect;
}
```

Note that my right (left) view width is 30.

If you happen to use both left and right view, and clear button, then this solution obviously won't work. In that case you will have to give up using one of those, and use a separate view put next to your UITextField.